# PHP 5.3.8 doesn't load module xapian.so

Tags: linux, nginx, php5, php-fpm, xapian

I have web server on fedora 16 nginx + php-fpm (PHP 5.3.8),all installed with yum from standard repo. I'm trying to use xapian.so module so I istalled php-xapian and added extension=xapian.so to my php config files in /etc/php.d.

After restarting php-fpm and execute php -m in command line im getting error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xapian.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xapian.so: undefined symbol: zend_error_noreturn in Unknown on line 0

My first thought was that it is problem with file location but xapian.so is where it should be /usr/lib64/php/modules/xapian.so

Have any one had similar problem with running xapian module on php 5.3 ??

How to make it work?

EDIT:
I've tried to compile xapian 1.2.8 and install from repo version 1.2.7 both doesn't work. But version 1.2.5 compiled load xapian module without problems. So what is wrong with xapian >1.2.7 and php 5.3.8???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xapian 1.2.8 and 1.2.7 doesnt work (first compiled second installed from base repo). Why I dont know. I wrote a letter to xapian mailing list but nobody answer.

After hours of struggling I tried compile version 1.2.5 and it work perfectly